# VS 2022 can not start because ServiceHub.IdentityHost.exe failed to start

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Recently my vs 2022 could not start, and after investigation found it is because one of its dependent service 'ServiceHub.IdentityHost.exe' failed to start, which locates at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.netfx.x86

the error message in event viewer is:
[image]

I can not start this service manually as well, it mentions something went wrong with config file, tried checked the dependent assemblies in the configuration file, looks like they are either in gac or in privatehost folder, can not figure out what goes wrong

[image]

[image]

not sure what else I can do(already tried reinstall vs)

any help is highly appreciated